# Unable to load addressable from remote storage WEBGL Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl, addressables

I am getting an error:
"RemoteProviderException : Unable to load asset bundle from : https://storage.googleapis.com/ice-fishing-android.appspot.com/******/defaultlocalgroup_assets_all_d405c0a311875b4b6260cc274ac0e5d2.bundle
UnityWebRequest result : ConnectionError : Unknown Error
ResponseCode : 500, Method : GET

It's happens when I try to load addressable assets from google storage or any other storage.

I can successfully download these assets from the link.
I start the game on my localhost server using XAMPP.
When I change the link in addressable profile to http://localhost/games/***/*** everthing works perfectly.

What do I need to do to use addressable with google storage?

Unity 2021.3.17f1
Addressable 1.19.19

=============================================

I figured out what was wrong. The problem is in Google Storage or other cloud storage.
All you need is to set up CORS configuration on your hosting or locate your assets on the same hosting where WEBGL is located.

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cors-configurations